# How can we do default selection from select using Angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-forms

I have to use the drop down for a field named "reportType". I extracted the value from API as `Reportformdetails.reportType`.

The `Reportformdetails.reportType` contains two values, such as A and B

I used the below code:

```html
    <select  class="form-control"  name="reportType"  #reportType="ngModel" ngModel
            [(ngModel)]="Reportformdetails.reportType" (change)="selectInput($event)" >
        <option [value]="undefined"> Select </option>
        <option [value]="x.value" *ngFor="let x of services" >{{x.name}}</option>
     </select>
```

Now when I see the dropdown, the value A has to be selected by default.

In normal HTML, I can use the selected attribute directly in option value. What do I do here?

Comment: Use null instead of undefined, and set the default value of Reportformdetails.reportType to null

Answer (score 1):

Set `Reportformdetails.reportType` to `A` from ts

Try like this:

```
Reportformdetails.reportType= 'A'
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g1nrjk?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**